# Parse responses from JSON response

Tags: javascript

```
async sendMessage(message) {
    const slackEndpoint = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/........';
    return await axios.post(slackEndpoint,
      {text: message})
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

let response = await this.sendMessage(message);
this.logger.info('Sending Slack message for amount threshold: ' + message);
console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!! ", response.statusText )

if (response.statusText == 'OK') {
  this.logger.info('sent');
}
else {
  this.logger.error('NOT send!');
}
```

I get response:

```
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: {
    date: 'Thu, 09 Dec 2021 17:29:29 GMT',
  ..............
}
```

And error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statusText')
```

Do you know how I can properly get the value of `statusText` and compare it?

Comment: can you log response?

Comment: the begging of the response is into the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
async sendMessage(message) {
    const slackEndpoint = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/........';
    return await axios.post(slackEndpoint,
      {text: message})
      .then(response => response)
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

Comment: What about setting timeout in seconds in axios? Is it possible?